# Are the poles of a hollow electromagnet on the ring or in the center?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields

**Question:**

Will this work as I've shown it here, more or less, or will the iron cylinder being hollow produce results not shown?

**Topic:**

I'm experimenting with magnetic fields and have been testing electromagnets. For a specific device that I'm interested in engineering, I'll need to look at the effects of a hollow iron tube wrapped by a standard charged wire coil. The reason that it needs to be hollow is that other machinery will need to fit down the center of the device.

This is what I'm expecting from this:

**Model 1:**

[image]

In this model, the poles originate from the edges of the cylinder.

Another possibility that I thought might occur would be this model:

Model 2:

[image]

Here, the poles originate from the object's true center.

**Are either of these models accurate? If not, what's the answer?**

Comment: You might want to read the Wiki article on [solenoids](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solenoid)

Comment: Ok, I'll read it.

Comment: Well, it looks from that article, my second model is accurate, with the exception that I should have the south pole arrows facing inward, but then again, this model isn't for a science magazine ^_^

Comment: Actually, neither model is correct, either qualitatively or quantitatively. It might be helpful to look at the picture of the field lines in the Wiki solenoid article again, just to see the correct geometry of the lines. You may also find it quite helpful to look at what the field that comes out of a straight piece of wire looks like, since it's particularly simple. In any case, both pictures clearly violate $\nabla \cdot {\bf B}=0$, so you immediately know something is not right even without Wiki.

Comment: Ah, I think I now understand your comment about the yellow arrows pointing the wrong way. If the yellow arrows are reversed in direction and changed to a red color, then yes, it's correct (different colors are actually superfluous when drawing magnet lines, which is why I was a bit confused).

Comment: @DumpsterDoofus Right, right. I for some reason used them the way I had originally, simply, looked at the way the negatively/positively charged end of the wire coil correlated with the direction of the poles.